# Jscript/Ajax to return PHP without page reload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, phpexcel

Complete novice but making progress. Please assist in getting form data to php and back without a page refresh. I know this should require JQuery / AJAX. I have tried multiple methods (serialize/dataform) but I am stumped. The goal is to fill in a listbox on form.php with headers acquired with PHPExcel from an Excel file PRIOR to being uploaded / tmp (no fopen etc) via lbox.php.  All code below works.  ** I am not looking to submit the data with the button YET, this should be called when a file has been chosen to be uploaded**

form.php

```
<html>
<head> 
<title>Testing Page</title> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script = "text/javascript">

window.onload = startChecking;

function startChecking()
{
var  myVar = setInterval(doFunction, 1000);
}

function doFunction()
{
 var nme= document.getElementById("file");
 var x=document.getElementById("right");
    if(nme.value.length<1){
    document.getElementById("right").style.display="none";
    return false;
                 }
    document.getElementById("right").style.display="block";
//CODE NEEDED TO LOAD THE LISBOX THAT IS NOW APPEARING
    clearInterval(myVar);
}
</script>
</head> 
<body>

<form action="lbox.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="creationform" id="frmCreate"> 
Project Name:
<input type="text" name="YourName" value="Testing">
<br><br>
Choose your file: <br> 
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
<input type="submit" name="Create" value="Create" /> 
</form>

<div id = "right" style="display:none">
Below should be the data from PHP loaded into the listbox
<BR>
<!-- //This code takes our array of headers and builds them into a listbox -->
<select size="15" name="decision1" multiple>
<?php foreach($myArray as $key => $value) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $key ?>"><?php echo $value ?></option> -->
<?php }?>
</select>
</div>

</body> 
</html>
```

lbox.php

```
<?php
include 'PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

// This code creates our concatenation of column headers
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
$val2 = null;
//    $highestRow         = $worksheet->getHighestDataRow(); // e.g. 10
    $highestRow         = 1; // e.g. 10
    $highestColumn      = $worksheet->getHighestDataColumn(); // e.g 'F'
    $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
    $nrColumns = ord($highestColumn) - 64;
    for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; ++ $row) {
        for ($col = 0; $col < $highestColumnIndex; ++ $col) {
            $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
            $val2 .= $cell->getValue().',';
            $dataType = PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::dataTypeForValue($val2);

        }

    }

}

//The code below gets rid of the extra comma at the end
$val2 = substr($val2,0,strlen($val2)-1);
$val2 .= '';
echo '<br />';

// This code takes our concatenation and turns it into an array with the comma delimiter
$myString = $val2;
$myArray = explode(',',$myString);
print_r($myArray);
echo '<br />';

?>
```

Thanks, Mark.

Comment: Study [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)

Comment: @RaxWeber Thanks I have been able to use AJAX to aquire a simple "hello" from another php file, but that has been the furthest I could make it. This is a little more complicated and I've worked on it hours with no success.

Comment: To run PHP code on a file chosen by the user, you still have to upload it first. How else is PHP supposed to read the file?

Comment: That is one of the beautys of PHPExcel, PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']); uses the tmp filename in PHP. If I combine these two files, it works without an upload.